# Como puedo solucionar que las llaves de un switch, tanto como la abrir para cerrar se detecten?

Tags: php, html

Estoy utilizando un `switch` en `php` pero el problema es cuando le agrego un segundo case, porque en cuanto lo agrego se dejan de detectar las llaves del `switch` y por consiguiente no hace el proceso.

**Sé que tiene que ver algo con las llaves para abrir y cerrar código php, sin embargo no he logrado detectar donde se encuentra el problema**

¿Como podría arreglar este error?

He estado revisando las partes en las que abro código `php` y en las que lo cierro pero no doy con el problema y también he estado revisando las veces que abro y cierro `html` pero tampoco he tenido suerte.

Escribo esta duda porque aun soy un novato en `php` y la verdad aun no se como resolver este problema, repito se que es algo con la forma de abrir y cerrar `php` pero aun no tengo el conocimiento para saber donde puedo encontrar el problema, si alguien me pudiera ayudar lo agradecería muchisimo!!

```
<?
session_start();
echo $_SESSION[boton];
echo $_SESSION[busq];

switch ($_SESSION[boton]) {

case 1:
require('Conexion_situaciones.php');
$conexion=mysqli_query($Conexion_pagina,"select * from robos_varios where 
id='$_SESSION[busq]' ");
if( $Busca=mysqli_num_rows($conexion)>=1)
  {
    while ($barrido=mysqli_fetch_array($conexion)) {

    ?>
    <html>
    <br>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $_SESSION[boton]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="Actualizado.php" method="POST">
    Tipo robo:
    <input size="50" name="T_robo" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Tipo_de_robo]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    Numero de detenidos:
    <input size="50" name="N_detenidos" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[No_Detenidos]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
     Nombre de Detenido(s):
    <input size="50" name="D_nombre" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Detenidos_Nombre]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
     Nombre de Agente(s):
    <input size="50" name="N_agentes" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Nombre_Agentes]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
     Unidad(es):
    <input size="50" name="Unidad_s" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Unidad]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    Fecha y Hora:
    <input size="50" name="F_Hora" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Fecha_Hora]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
     Dirección de los sucesos:
    <input size="50" name="D_sucesos" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Dirección_de_los_sucesos]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Actualizar</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </html>

    <?  
    mysqli_close($Conexion_pagina);

    }

  }
  else
  {
    echo "Lo sentimos el caracter que ingresaste no existe, verifica la id...";
  }
    break;


    case 2: 
    require('Conexion_situaciones.php');
    $conexion=mysqli_query($Conexion_pagina,"select * from reportes_varios 
    where id='$_POST[busq]' ");
    if( $Busca=mysqli_num_rows($conexion)>=1)
    {
    while ($barrido=mysqli_fetch_array($conexion)) {

    ?>
    <html>
    <br>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $_SESSION[boton]; ?>">
      <br>
      <br>
      <form action="Actualizado.php" method="POST">
    Tipo robo:
    <input size="50" name="T_reporte" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Tipo_de_reporte]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    Numero de Apoyados:
    <input size="50" name="N_apoyados" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[No_Apoyados]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
     Nombre de Apoyado(s):
    <input size="50" name="A_nombre" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Apoyados_Nombre]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
     Nombre de Agente(s):
    <input size="50" name="N_agentes3" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Nombre_Agentes]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
     Unidad(es):
    <input size="50" name="Unidad_s3" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Unidad]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    Fecha y Hora:
    <input size="50" name="F_Hora3" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Fecha_Hora]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
     Dirección de los sucesos:
    <input size="50" name="D_sucesos3" type="text" value="<? echo $barrido[Dirección_de_los_sucesos]; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Actualizar</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </html>

    <?  
    mysqli_close($Conexion_pagina);

    }

  }
  else
  {
    echo "Lo sentimos el caracter que ingresaste no existe, verifica la id...";
  } 
    break;

    }



   ?>
```

Comment: solo te falta la llave de cierre en el while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo unico  que te falta es el cierre de el case en el switch , te pongo un ejemplo:

```html
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i es igual a 0";
        break;
```

[fuente](http://fhttps://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta corta es:

```
<?php para abrir, no <?
```

La respuesta larga, ya que comentas que eres novato te comento que cualquier duda que tengas en programación vas a encontrar una respuesta en internet y sera siempre más rápido que preguntar cada duda aquí. Si buscas "abrir y cerrar php" vas a encontrar la respuesta fácilmente.

Extra para ti:

Formatea el código para ver fácilmente posibles llaves que te dejes y ver más claramente el código. Hay maneras automáticas con IDEs como por ejemplo, eclipse pulsando CTRL+Mayus+F.

Comment: lo que le faltaba era la llave de cierre al final.

Comment: Si que tiene el "break", esta después del código html.